# Opening a .ipynb.txt File

Tags: python

I have got downloaded a file that got downloaded in a format .pynb.txt extension. Can anyone help me to figure how to make it in a readable format?
Attaching a screenshot of the file when i tried opening in python notebook.

[image: Output of the python notebook when tried to open a file with extension .pynb.txt]

Comment: I'd guess that it's JSON, but details would help a lot. Where did you get it from? What do you need it for? To deal with JSON, use: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: Thanks things worked fine by suggestions.. thanks alot

Answer (score 50):

What you have on your hands is an [IPython Notebook](https://ipython.org/notebook.html) file. (Now renamed to [Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter.org/)

you can open it using the command `ipython notebook filename.ipynb` from the directory it is downloaded on to.

If you are on a newer machine, open the file as `jupyter notebook filename.ipynb`.

do not forget to remove the .txt extension.

the file has a series of python code/statements and markdown text that you can run/inspect/save/share. read more about ipython notebook from the website.

if you do not have IPython installed, you can do

`pip install ipython`

or check out installation instructions at the [ipython website](https://ipython.org/install.html)

Comment: You can use this app I created to automate this process, if you are running on OS X: https://github.com/alexisgaziello/JupyterNotebookTerminalOpen

Answer (score 9):

If you have a unix/linux system I'd just rename the file via command line

```
mv file_name.pynb.txt file_name.ipynb
```

worked like a charm for me!

Comment: It seems you are correct. But I think you can make it even more universal. It does not matter a) in which way rename was done (cli or not cli) b) which OS

Answer (score 7):

These steps work for me:

- Open the file in Jupyter Notebook.
- Rename the file: Click File > Rename, change the name so that it ends with '.ipynb' behind, and click OK
- Close the file.
- From the Jupyter Notebook's directory tree, click the filename to open it.

Comment: Thank you! Simple & effective.

Answer (score 5):

Try the following steps:

1. Download the file open it in the Juypter Notebook.
2. Go to **File** **-> Rename** and remove the **.txt** extension from the end; so now the file name has just **.ipynb** extension.
3. Now **reopen** it from the Juypter Notebook.

Answer (score 4):

I used to read jupiter nb files with this code:

```
import codecs
import json

f = codecs.open("JupFileName.ipynb", 'r')
source = f.read()

y = json.loads(source)
pySource = '##Python code from jpynb:\n'
for x in y['cells']:
     for x2 in x['source']:
         pySource = pySource + x2
         if x2[-1] != '\n':
            pySource = pySource + '\n'
print(pySource)
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the easiest way in case if **Anaconda** is already installed.

1) Under "**Files**", there is an option called,"**Upload**".

2) Click on "Upload" button and it asks for the path of the file and select 
   the file and click on upload button present beside the file.

Answer (score 1):

The trick that works is this:

*Open the file with jupyter notebook. It is not going to display properly, don't work.
Click on file > rename and remove the ".txt" attached to the file's name immediately after ".ipynb"
Close the file and reopen it.*

Enjoy it.

Answer (score 0):

go to cmd get into file directory and type
jupyter notebook filename.ipynb in my case it open code editor and provide local host connection string copy that string and paste in any browser!done

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar situation what I did is created a blank .ipynb file via Jupyter and replacted the code in the blank file.

CMD in Windows machine type jupyter notebook
Then Opened new IPY kernal
In the new IPY Kernal went to file>>Download as>> Notebook(.ipynb)
This will create a  blank  .ipynb file
opened that file in notepad and replaced the code.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue recently. (Using Linux)
What I did is-

1. searched for jupyter support in VsCodium(Visual Studio Code)
2. the package named "ms-python" is the support for jupyter which opens ".ipynb" file.

[Click on the second ext in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIf2L.png)

Another way of opening a ".ipynb" file is simply opening it on the jupyter online [Jupyter online](https://jupyter.org/try) you can upload your files and continue

Answer (score 0):

- Upload the file on Jupyter Notebook with (.ipynb.txt) format.
- Single click on the file name.
- Rename it.
- Click Save.

Works for me as of 9/17/2022